# Cleaning up after two threads finish execution

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have an application that is running jobs that require two threads for every job. The two threads normally do some work and finish shortly after each other. Then after the second thread finishes I need to do some cleanup but since the threads are doing some network IO, it is possible for one thread to get blocked for a long time. In that case, I want the cleanup to take place a few seconds after the first thread finishes.

I implemented this behaviour with the following piece of code in a callback class:

```
private boolean first = true;

public synchronized void done() throws InterruptedException {
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        wait(3000);
        // cleanup here, as soon as possible
    }
    else {
        notify();
    }
}
```

Both threads invoke the done() method when they finish. The first one will then block in the wait() for at most 3 seconds but will be notified immediately when the seconds thread invokes the done() method.

I have tested this implementation and it seems to work well but I'm am curious if there's a better way of doing this. Even though this implementation doesn't look too complicated, I'm afraid that my program will deadlock or have some unsuspected synchronization issue.

Comment: how can thread two access done() while thread 1 is in it?

Comment: @nafas - `wait` releases the lock.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon ahh lol yeah, for some reason I was thinking about Thread.sleep(...). my bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your need. You want to wait for thread-a to complete and then wait either 3 seconds or for the end of thread-b.

It is better to use the newer `Concurrent` tools instead of the old `wait/notify` as there are so many edge cases to them.

```
// Two threads running so count down from 2.
CountDownLatch wait = new CountDownLatch(2);

class TestRun implements Runnable {

    private final long waitTime;

    public TestRun(long waitTime) {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Wait a few seconds.
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            // Finished! Count me down.
            wait.countDown();
            System.out.println(new Date() + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Interrupted");
        }
    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // ThreadA
    Thread threadA = new Thread(new TestRun(10000), "Thread A");
    // ThreadB
    Thread threadB = new Thread(new TestRun(30000), "Thread B");
    // Fire them up.
    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
    // Wait for all to finish but threadA must finish.
    threadA.join();
    // Wait up to 3 seconds for B.
    wait.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(new Date() + ": Done");
    threadB.join();
}
```

happily prints:

```
Tue Sep 15 16:59:37 BST 2015: Thread A - Finished
Tue Sep 15 16:59:40 BST 2015: Done
Tue Sep 15 16:59:57 BST 2015: Thread B - Finished
```

---

**Added**

With the new clarity - that the end of any thread starts the timer - we can use a third thread for the cleanup. Each thread must call a method when it finishes to trigger the cleanup mechanism.

```
// Two threads running so count down from 2.
CountDownLatch wait = new CountDownLatch(2);

class TestRun implements Runnable {

    private final long waitTime;

    public TestRun(long waitTime) {
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Wait a few seconds.
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            // Finished! Count me down.
            wait.countDown();
            System.out.println(new Date() + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Finished");
            // Record that I've finished.
            finished();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Interrupted");
        }
    }

}

Runnable cleanup = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Wait up to 3 seconds for both threads to clear.
            wait.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // Do your cleanup stuff here.
            // ...
            System.out.println(new Date() + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Interrupted");
        }
    }

};

final AtomicBoolean cleanupStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private void finished() {
    // Make sure I only start the cleanup once.
    if (cleanupStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        new Thread(cleanup, "Cleanup").start();
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    // ThreadA
    Thread threadA = new Thread(new TestRun(10000), "Thread A");
    // ThreadB
    Thread threadB = new Thread(new TestRun(30000), "Thread B");
    // Fire them up.
    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
    System.out.println(new Date() + ": Done");
}
```

Comment: Either thread may finish first. I want to clean up right after the second thread finishes but no longer than 3 seconds after the first thread finishes.

Comment: @Gert-Jan - In that case instead of `threadA.join()` use `while (wait.getCount() > 1) {Thread.sleep(1000);}` - not so pretty but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for example, I will try to write an implementation with a `CountDownLatch`. Using sleep is not a good option because I really need to clean up as soon as possible and the sleep will introduce an extra delay.

Comment: @Gert-Jan - Second option allows for either thread finishing first.

Comment: Great, looks like this does exactly what I need, without wait() and notify(). The downside is a lot more code and an extra thread, but I guess you can't have it all ;)

Answer (score 0):

As `done` method is synchronized, so only one thread can execute at a time, with this second will wait to send notify until first finishes its whole job, which might cause performance bottleneck.

I would rather design it with short **synchronized block** which would primarily update the `boolean first`.

Comment: `wait` releases the lock so the second thread can continue as soon as the first thread invokes `wait`

Comment: If I account that then there would a race condition, if second thread invokes after 3 seconds & also in first place why first thread should for three extra seconds?

Comment: There can only be one running thread in the synchronized method so there cannot be a race condition. The 3 seconds is a grace period to allow the second thread to finish what it is doing, although normally the threads should finish within a few milliseconds after eachother.

Comment: You did not get the point, I said what if 2nd thread reaches after when 1st thread completes waiting of 3 seconds, 2nd thread will wait until the 1st thread releases the object lock. 
I would prefer no grace period, where the job can be done with almost no time. And also in case if this threads start doing time consuming task, then this grace period may be inappropriate.